# Link to add public Google calendar to our calendar view

Tags: hyperlink, calendar, google-calendar-api

We would like to share our calendar to the public, so that interpreters and companies can add the calendar to their own personal calendar view.

We know that each calendar can be made public and has its own link, like ours:
https://calendar.google.com/calendar/ical/pt1fre4229hs8ddfd8uq0no78g%40group.calendar.google.com/private-fa9e2ac63d62d57ca70f3650ac29682b/basic.ics

However, clicking on this link does not produce anything useful.

We would like an HTML link that, when clicked, would go the the person's Google calendar view, and add this calendar to their calendar list.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a link like this, with the Google Calendar ID that you wish to share:
`https://calendar.google.com/calendar/r?cid=THE_GOOGLE_CALENDAR_ID_YOU_WISH_TO_SHARE`

Can't seem to find any documentation about it, however this does exactly what the OP is requesting, which is to **"add this calendar to [a user's] calendar list"**. So in the OP's case, this link should do the trick:

> https://calendar.google.com/calendar/r?cid=pt1fre4229hs8ddfd8uq0no78g%40group.calendar.google.com

Clicking the above link (or pasting it into a web browser) on a desktop PC will open the user's Google Calendar, with prompt: *"Add calendar - Freelensia Interpreter Events (Vietnam)? CANCEL / ADD"* so the user just has to click "ADD" and the Calendar is now subscribed.

### Where is my Google Calendar ID?

1. In the Google Calendar interface, locate the "My calendars" area on the left.
2. Hover over the calendar you need and click the vertical ellipsis (three vertical dots).
3. A menu will appear. Click "Settings and sharing".
4. In the "Integrate calendar" section of the screen, you will see your Calendar ID. It will look something like **"abc123@group.calendar.google.com"**.

Comment: Perfect! Three years on and this (1) is still undocumented and (2) still works, even with the example link provided.

Answer (score 0):

First make sure your calendar is public then do this steps:

1. Go to your **Calendar Settings**.
2. Note the **Embed This Calendar** section. You'll see some html codes for iframe like:

   < iframe src="https://calendar.google.com/calendar/embed?src=classroom123456789%40group.calendar.google.com" style="border: 0" width="800" height="600" frameborder="0" scrolling="no">

Copy the link that's in src:

```
https://calendar.google.com/calendar/embed?src=classroom123456789%40group.calendar.google.com
```

That's the link you're looking for.